# Simple User-Interface with ZinoUI within HTML/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, user-interface

I would like to create an user friendly interface on my site where from a php restrictred area of the site I can add a simple HTML to another open page of the site.

The simple HTML (below "BASIC HTML") has always the same structure, I want the user to change the words inside the header,the main div and to upload a new image.

I'm struggling about how to do it. A nice idea i had is to use [ZinoUI](https://zinoui.com/demos/editable#custom-2), sothat in the restricted area i can show the basic HTML and the user can modify it. It will be something like what shown in "ZinoUI HTML".

What I don't really know how to do is how to "print" this new HTML code modified by the user and insert it on the open page of the site.
Is it possible? is this the easier way?

BASIC HTML

```
<div id="simple HTML">

    <div class="header">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</h1>  
    </div>

    <div class="main">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </div>

    <div class="image">
    <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View">
    </div>

</div>
```

.
    ZinoUI HTML

```
        <div class="header" id="editable">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</h1>  
        </div>

        <div class="main" id="editable">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </div>

        <div class="image" id="editable">
        <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View">
        </div>
<p>To activate editable control, double click on the text above.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#editable").zinoEditable({
        control: "textarea",
        event: "dblclick"
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, each HTML `id` must be unique, so you don't want to have a series of `<div id="editable">...</div>`.

What you can do is add an editable class `<div class="editable">..</div>` if you are going to have more than one editable div and use

```
$(function () {
  $(".editable").zinoEditable({
      control: "textarea",
      event: "dblclick"
  });
});
```

Then to save you subscribe to the [save](https://zinoui.com/docs/editable) event, say passing in the control's id doing the save and the edited text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $(".editable").zinoEditable({
            buttons: {
                "Save": function (ui) {
                    $(this).zinoEditable("save");
                },
                "Cancel": function (ui) {
                    $(this).zinoEditable("close");
                }
            },
            save: function (event, ui) {
                $.post("../../request?plugin=editable", {
                    field: $(this).attr("id"),
                    value: ui.control.val()
                });
                console.log("save");
                //return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where `"../../request?plugin=editable"` is the PHP function to call to save the data (although replace with whatever is appropriate for you).

Comment: and I should add you will need to give each `div` a unique `id` as well, since that is being passed back in the sample code above